# interaction between two agents, not within the statechart

Tags: communication, interaction, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I have defined a population of agents called "Sellers" and one agent with a population of 1 called "Manufacturer". "AverageSales" is defined in the statistics for the sellers agents. Now I want to let the Manufacturer know different values taken by "AverageSales" of the Sellers. I think for this communication, I should send a message from Sellers in which the values of "AverageSales" be sent to the Manufacturer. The problem is all the examples have defined a message within a statechart. How can I do that? Can you please write me the piece of code for this action and where to add it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Agent communication does not always have to be via messages. (That is just something that fits with a statechart-oriented view of agent behaviour and is stressed in many of AnyLogic's example models.) In many cases (as in yours) it is much simpler just to access the information directly in the other agent (or its population).

In your case, your Manufacturer agents can just access the statistics value directly. Say you have populations `manufacturers` and `sellers` in `Main`, with statistic `AverageSales` as you said. From within one of your Manufacturer agents, you can just do `main.sellers.AverageSales()` to access the statistic (i.e., go up to `Main` via the link-to-upper-level-agent created for you, then into the sellers population and access the statistic value via the provided function).

Look at the help for:

- Advanced Modeling with Java --> Java Basics for AnyLogic --> Where am I and how do I get to…?
- Release Notes --> What's new in previous releases --> What's new in AnyLogic 7 --> Link to upper level agent
- Agent Based Modeling --> Collecting statistics on agents